# Pandas concatenate list columns with groupby when grouping on multiple columns

Tags: python, combinatorics

I am trying to perform a simple groupby operation on a Pandas dataframe with list columns (with the goal of concatenating the lists corresponding to each group). It works fine when grouping on a single column, but for reasons I can't explain fails when grouping on two columns. A simplified example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2],'b':['a','a','a','b'],'c':[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]})

   a  b       c
0  1  a  [1, 2]
1  1  a  [3, 4]
2  2  a  [5, 6]
3  2  b  [7, 8]
```

Now, grouping on either `a` or `b` works as expected:

```
x.groupby('b')['c'].sum()

b
a    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b                [7, 8]
dtype: object

x.groupby('a')['c'].sum()

a
1    [1, 2, 3, 4]
2    [5, 6, 7, 8]
dtype: object
```

But if I try to group on `a` AND `b` (i.e. `x.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].sum()`), it invariably fails with `ValueError: Function does not reduce`.

On the surface I can't see why this should happen, as either way we're just concatenating lists, but I imagine it has something to do with Pandas internals...

Any workarounds or explanations?

Comment: This works fine if column `c` is a numeric column, so I'm guessing this has to do with the `sum` function not understanding what to do with the lists. Sometimes it will do the right thing, but for some reason the way it's called the second time around messes it up.

Comment: Ah, good point. I should have checked that. In any case, I think @kabanus is right that this is likely a bug (if we're being pythonic, `sum` should handle lists without hiccups).

Comment: Definitely a bug, but now I'm curious to see in the source code how the `.apply(sum)` makes the `sum` function work on lists, while the `.sum()` doesn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be a bug, where sum fails when some rows can't be summed, the last two for example will remain split with the double grouping. The workaround is apply:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2],'b':['a','a','a','b'],'c':[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]})
print x
   a  b       c
0  1  a  [1, 2]
1  1  a  [3, 4]
2  2  a  [5, 6]
3  2  b  [7, 8]
print  x.groupby(('a'))['c'].apply(sum)
a
1    [1, 2, 3, 4]
2    [5, 6, 7, 8]
Name: c, dtype: object
print x.groupby(('a'))['c'].sum()
a
1    [1, 2, 3, 4]
2    [5, 6, 7, 8]
dtype: object
print x.groupby(('a','b'))['c'].apply(sum)
a  b
1  a    [1, 2, 3, 4]
2  a          [5, 6]
   b          [7, 8]
Name: c, dtype: object
```

I think you should submit this to the pandas team as well.